# RDS Accessible but fails password auth when not in VPC

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm unable to connect to my RDS instance from my local computer despite following the documentation. The problem is, I can connect from an ec2 instance in the VPC, but when using the same credentials on my local machine I get "incorrect password".

**What I've tried:**

I've configured RDS for public access, followed the troubleshooting documentation here: [RDS Troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/)
Additionally:

- Confirm RDS is publicly accessible √
- Confirm Subnet ACL allows postgres traffic √
- Connect internet gateway to VPC √
- Associate public subnets with public route tables √
- Enable VPC dns resolution √
- Enable incoming postgres traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 in security group √

I was even able to test connectivity locally and confirm that I am in fact able to connect to the RDS instance using the below command on my local computer:

`nc -zv <rds.dns> <port>`

which returns:

`xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com [ip.address] 5432 (postgresql) open`

This signals to me that my computer has network access to the RDS instance, and yet, when I try to login using the PSQL command:

```
sudo psql \
   --host=xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
   --port=5432 \
   --username=<dbuser> \
   --password \
   --dbname=<dbname>
```

I am then prompted for my password, which I get:

```
...
Password:
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

The weird part is this password works fine from within an ec2 instance inside the VPC, so I'm completely at a loss as to why the password auth is failing from my psql client on my local computer.

Any help, documentation or references would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try from an EC2 outside the vpc through public route?

Comment: Have you tried connecting using postgres GUI clients bro?

Comment: Might be related to: [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 14: 21.1. The pg_hba.conf File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

Comment: That error message is coming from sudo, not from PostgreSQL.  PostgreSQL doesn't word its messages that way, and doesn't give you 3 chances.  And obviously doesn't prefix its messages with 'sudo:'

Comment: Oof, the issue was using 'sudo', without using sudo, I am able to connect outside of the VPC using the above configuration... Good catch! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was in the command

```
sudo psql \
   --host=xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
   --port=5432 \
   --username=<dbuser> \
   --password \
   --dbname=<dbname>
```

As @jjanes pointed out, the error was using 'sudo' for this command.

```
psql \
   --host=xxx.xxx.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com \
   --port=5432 \
   --username=<dbuser> \
   --password \
   --dbname=<dbname>
```

With the above configuration in the VPC worked as expected.